# WP "TypeError: blacklist is undefined" password-strength-meter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, user-profile

I am creating a custom profile page for one of my WP plugins, where I want the user to have a regular page instead of seeing the WP Dashboard. All works fine so far, except the script for the password-strength. When I start typing the password, I get this in my Firebug console:

```
TypeError: blacklist is undefined
  blacklist = [ blacklist.toString() ];
```

Which is thrown when the "meter" event is called at the beginning:

```
meter : function( password1, blacklist, password2 ) {
  if ( ! $.isArray( blacklist ) )
    blacklist = [ blacklist.toString() ];
```

I have no idea what it's working fine in the WP dashboard. I spend about an hour searching, then I decided to use a workaround. If anybody could point me into the right direction, what I am missing here, I would appreciate that.

My workaround for now is to put this into a try/catch block:

```
meter : function( password1, blacklist, password2 ) {
  try {
        if ( ! $.isArray( blacklist ) )
            blacklist = [ blacklist.toString() ];
  }
  catch (e){}
```

Which works fine now, even when I use it on the WP front end. But it's not an optimal solution, as I have to copy the JS files password-strenght-meter.js to my own plugin and enqueue it from there. Since I also need to use the user-profile.js, I also have to copy this too, so I need to duplicate these two JS files which is not a good solution.

Any ideas, why jQuery is stopping the script when used on a front end page, while it works fine on the admin backend?

==== EDIT ========
I just found that the problem is related to another plugin "WP User Frontend" which seems to override the password-strenght-meter script with their own code. So I think I will be able to fix this now.

Comment: So are you not passing in a blacklist to the method?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the misleading question. I have checked that this problem was related to having another plugin "WP User Frontent" activated, that did interfere with the existing admin scripts from WordPress. So here is how I solved it.

First of all, I put this into a custom page template, so this needs to be placed in the theme directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: User Profile Dashboard
 */


// remove other conflicting scripts
if (class_exists('WPUF_Main'))
{
  global $wpuf;

  remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($wpuf, 'enqueue_scripts') );
}

get_header();

wp_enqueue_script('user-profile');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-admin');


include_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/template.php');

... other code that handles the user profile fields ...

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

The tricky part was to get rid of the already enqueued scripts that came from the WPUF_Main class. It seems that WP User Frontend instantiates the class into a global variable $wpuf when the plugin is active, so I had to use this variable to remove the action for enqueuing the scripts. Then I enqueued the scripts and styles for user-profile and wp-admin, and included template.php from wp-admin, because I needed the function submit_button() which is declared here.

I hope this will help others who come up with the same problem, because the combination of WP User Frontend and having a custom Profile page, does make sense, when the webmaster don't want to have their users to see the WP Dashboard at all.